# Difference between lpszName and lpszAddress in MAPI

Tags: c#, email, mapi

Recently I have been working on sending mail with MAPI. We are required to prefill some of the fields and be able to have a mail client dialog opened and ready for editing and finally sending.

Problem I have encountered is to do with MapiRecipDesc structure(or in my class class). Two fields have understandable names yet they do not translate very well to the process it self. For instance, if I pass an actual email address to field lpszName I will be able to send the mail. However, if I pass it to lpszAddress the mail will not be sent and MAPISendMail method will return 2 which is general MAPI error.

If you look at the structure definition of [MapiRecipDesc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd296720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you will clearly see that name is reserved for display name of the recipient and address is reserved for the actual email address of the recipient.

If I provide both address and name and I assign them accordingly: address to lpszAddress and name to lpszName - email client will load the dialog and fields will be prefilled but if I try and send the mail it will fail saying the following recipients(than quoted the actual display name and not the email) cannot be found.

Why is he treating name field as address and how do we send display name along with the email?

Comment: What is the actual example value in the LPSTR where lpszAddress points to?

Comment: @rene I'm not following you but here goes nothing. For lpszAddress I would put 'john.johnson@something.com' and for lpszName I would put 'John Johnson'.

Comment: But the spec says you need a type and then an address: *The format of the address is address type:email address. Examples of valid addresses are FAX:206-555-1212 and SMTP:M@X.COM.* If you only put plain  email address there I expect you are braking the rulez that govern that field.

Comment: @rene Yes it does. If I assemble my address as 'SMTP:john.johnson@something.com' it still doesn't work. I am begining to think that the lsszName is the actual email address and that this is all just a big typo from Microsoft side.

Comment: It might be along shot but maybe the lpszName accepts an `<John Johnson> john.johnson@something.com` format. Then you can leave lpszAddress empty

Comment: @rene It does accept it but I do not know how that translates to other mail clients. Will they be able to recognize the display name between '<>'. Funny enough, if I have John Johnson in my address book I can provide 'John Johnson' to lpszName and completely forget about lpszAddress and the mail will be sent. However, if I provide nothing to name and set lpszAddress to 'SMTP:john.johnson@something.com' it will fail with 2 - general MAPI error. If I provide gibberish to lpszName while setting lpszAddress to 'SMTP:john.johnson@something.com' than it will be successful.

Comment: It looks like an accepted standard: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4